# Spring JSON to Map Deserialization Failing

Tags: java, json, spring, deserialization

I am trying to use Spring to deserialize incoming JSON objects. I have the following class:

```
public class ContentRequestMessage {
    
    private String type;

    private String messageId;

    private String topicArn;
    
    /**
     * Message contents:
     * 
     * "Message" : "{"location": "/interactments/d2734-9304cceb7c3a", "status": "draft_created"}"
     */
    private Map<String, Object> message;

    private Date timestamp;

    private String signatureVersion;

    private String signature;

    private String signingCertURL;

    private String unsubscribeURL;
    
    private Map<String, Object> messageAttributes;
    
    //constructors, getters & setters
}
```

I am trying to feed the following JSON request:

```
{
  "type" : "Notification",
  "messageId" : "b2b769284",
  "topicArn" : "arn:aws:sn",
  "message" : "{\"location\": \"/interacments/d275d0-893ceb7c3a\", \"status\": \"draft_created\"}",
  "timestamp" : "2023-01-03T11:17:29.537Z",
  "signatureVersion" : "1",
  "signature" : "1Jag1w==",
  "signingCertURL" : "https://2625d385.pem",
  "unsubscribeURL" : "httbscri2b1f502953",
  "messageAttributes" : {
    "scope" : {"Type":"String","Value":"nas_consumer"}
  }
}
```

Into my controller:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    
    @PostMapping
    public void postRequest(@RequestBody ContentRequestMessage contentRequestMessage) {
        
        System.out.println(contentRequestMessage);
        
    }
}
```

But I am encountering the following error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"location": "/interactments/d2734-9304cceb7c3a", "status": "draft_created"}')
```

Other threads discuss using an ObjectMapper and Jackson, *but I want to rely on Spring to deserialize this object for me*. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `message` is not a map, but a simple `String`.

The content of `messageAttributes.scope` itself is a map again, and not an `Object`.

Try this:

```java
public class ContentRequestMessage {
  private String type;
  private String messageId;
  private String topicArn;
  private String message;
  private Date timestamp;
  private String signatureVersion;
  private String signature;
  private String signingCertURL;
  private String unsubscribeURL;
  private Map<String, Map<String, String>> messageAttributes;

  // rest of implementation
}
```

Comment: Message should be a map though. It contains key/value pairs, just like a map. I don't see why it can't be deserialized to a map?

Comment: But you passed a String (that contains parseable JSON, but that doesn't matter). If you want to parse the contents of that string, you will have to do it implicit in your method. Spring uses Jackson internally for parsing, so that would be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

> im a newcomer to StackOverflow

From your question, it seems to have a problem of serialize.

I guess you want to convert to this type:

```
message.get(location); //  "/interacments/d275d0-893ceb7c3a"
message.get(status);  //   "draft_created"
```

But on your `JSON request`:

```
{
"type" : "Notification",
"messageId" : "b2b769284",
"topicArn" : "arn:aws:sn",
"message" : "
            {\"location\": \"/interacments/d275d0-893ceb7c3a\", 
               \"status\": \"draft_created\"
            }",
"timestamp" : "2023-01-03T11:17:29.537Z",
"signatureVersion" : "1",
"signature" : "1Jag1w==",
"signingCertURL" : "https://2625d385.pem",
"unsubscribeURL" : "httbscri2b1f502953",
"messageAttributes" : { 
      "scope" : {"Type":"String","Value":"nas_consumer"}
    }
}
```

The field name `messageAttributes` is same of `message`, so why the `messageAttributes` not throw exception?

From the JSON perspective , the field `message` provides the String, `messageAttributes` provides the Map.

So this real problem is spring cannot deserialize String to Map.

```
{
 "message" : {
           "location": "interacments/d275d0-893ceb7c3a", 
           "status": "draft_created"
          }
 }
```